# Are Federated Learning and Model-Agnostic Meta-Learning the Same Thing?

Tags: machine-learning, meta-learning

I am currently reading this paper [[1](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9439935)] and [[2]](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.11028).

The author makes the claim that their Federated Learning scheme is similar to Model-Agnostic Meta-Learning?

They state:

> Interestingly, FFL is similar to Model-Agnostic Meta-Learning (MAML)
> in three aspects: (i) in FFL, we have workers who possess their own
> datasets (with different distributions) while in MAML, there are tasks
> with their corresponding datasets. (ii) In FFL, we have local updates that improve performances (loss/accuracy) of individual workers
> whereas in MAML, there are inner-loop updates that do so for
> individual tasks. (iii) In FFL, in each round, we apply global
> gradient to weights, which improves the overall performance of all
> workers while in MAML, the outer-loop update does so for all of tasks.

Are they right in proposing such a claim?

Comment: I haven't read those papers but have some familiarity with MAML. Are they making rigorous proofs showing that their method is a special case of the MAML objective? Or is this simply intuition? The intuition itself seems believable, at least.

Comment: They are comparing their scheme, FFL, with MAML at the algorithmic and implementation level. But I suspect the mathematical background from which MAML algorithm is derived differs from Federated Learning. As far as I know MAML is coming from bi-level optimization. Can we say in practice/implementation, Federated Learning and the vanilla MAML are the same?

Comment: Perhaps, we could even say that even at a mathematical level they're the same, where the workers in FL optimize inner-loops and the server optimizes the outer-loops?

Comment: So I think MAML has a slightly different motivation than what you're suggesting. MAML is motivated by multi-task learning for few-shot generalization, where each "worker" (so to speak) is learning from one task. FFL seems to be motivated by a better communication-computation tradeoff rather than few-shot multi-task generalization.

Comment: Both of them share a similar paradigm of bi-level optimization, or splitting up a larger problem into separable (inner) updates. "Mathematically they're the same" depends on the level of abstraction -- I think the connections are good for building intuition, but I'm not convinced that they're a rigorous statement.